# How can I do a resizing toolbar using glade 3?

Tags: gtk, glade

I want to do a resizing toolbar similar to the left hand bar in glade itself.  I believe Gimp has something similar.  An ascii art illustration below.

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| D | E | F |
```

So that when the width of the column is reduced, it flows down to something like this

```
| A | B |
---------
| C | D |
---------
| E | F |
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a wrapping table in GTK#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441108/how-to-create-a-wrapping-table-in-gtk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`GtkToolPalette`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkToolPalette.html).

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to click the green checkmark next to my answer - that's StackOverflow etiquette!

Comment: Done, sorry for the long delay